# How to create a local ubuntu repo?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

In my company we are planning to move from SuSE to Ubuntu as a distribution for development environment. Previously for Suse, we had a server hosting RPMs of our packages and a developer would download those RPMs using svn and install them.

Now, I want to create ubuntu repo of those packages so that a developer can use `apt-get` command to get the packages.

My question is:

How to create a repo from scratch for Ubuntu packages ?